# Remove duplicate adapter or SQL statement in android

Tags: android, sql, duplicates, adapter

I have the following code that takes records from a database and places them in an Adapter which then passes to a spinner . The issue is that I want to delete duplicates adapter but not the table. The code is as follows:

```
          try {
            Spinner spn2 = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spn2);     
            baseDatos = openOrCreateDatabase(nombreBD, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);                 
            Cursor cur5 = baseDatos.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT codigo AS _id, usuario FROM mensajeswatotal", null);  

            startManagingCursor(cur5);
            String[] from = new String[]{"usuario"};
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };           
            SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Vsms.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cur5, from, to); 

            mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

             spn2.setAdapter(mAdapter);                 

         } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a GROUP BY clause:

`"SELECT DISTINCT codigo AS _id, usuario FROM mensajeswatotal GROUP BY usuario"`